# How to control and take action for AtimatorSet (cancel(), resume() or end()) when CountdownTimer finished

Tags: java

It is my first Project(a simple Baloon Pop Game ) for a beginner level coder(Android). Please help me, thanks. Here is part of my code. :

```
public void balonlar_uret( ObjectAnimator balonx, ObjectAnimator balony,AnimatorSet balonxy){
    cd.start();

    for (balonlar_sayi=0; balonlar_sayi<balonlar.length-1;balonlar_sayi++) {

        balonlar[balonlar_sayi].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        balonlar[balonlar_sayi].setX(r.nextInt(600));
        balonlar[balonlar_sayi].setY(r.nextInt(800));

        balonx = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(balonlar[balonlar_sayi], "x", r.nextInt(1024));
        balony = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(balonlar[balonlar_sayi], "y", r.nextInt(2048));
        balonxy = new AnimatorSet();
        balonxy.playTogether(balonx, balony);
        balonxy.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        balonxy.setDuration(15000);
        balonxy.start();
    }
}
```

"cd" is my CountdownTimer

Comment: what issue do you have?

Comment: Hi. MY PURPOSE: when my Countdowntimer is finished, all of my array(balonlar[balonlar_sayi]) all items(all buttons/ballons' animation is Cancel or End Squentially.)

Comment: but ı dont know how to set up equation to handle this , or where should be codding ? in countdown timer's onFinish() method ? or in my method "balonlar_uret" method ? both of these could not help for reach my purpose.